# Does anyone here know how to create this in HTML? I'm struggling with it

Tags: html, css

[image: Photo Here]

So essentially I have a mockup of the webapp, and I want to have the margin below the mockup to always be 0 so it touches the bottom of the div.

Comment: Do you have any code to show or an example?

Comment: We cannot help without you posting the markup code (html).

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Setting

```
   margin-bottom: 0px;
```

on the image should do what you're looking to do if your image doesn't have any empty space below your mockup.